# Calculate Fibonacci numbers up to at least n

Tags: python, list, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to make a function that allows a user to input a number and the result will be a list containing Fibonacci numbers up to the input and one above if the input is not in the series. For example, input of `4` will return `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]` but input of `3` would return `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]`. I have managed to do this using the function below :

```
    def fibonacci(n):
        series = [0]
        if (n == 0):
            pass
        else:
            series.append(1)
            if (n == 1):
                pass
            else:
                while(series[len(series)-1] < n):
                    newValue = series[len(series)-1] + series[len(series)-2]
                    series.append(newValue)
        print(series)
```

However, I would now like to be able to do this recursively, any ideas?

Comment: Recursive fibonacci is simple to write, so where's your attempt?

Comment: Without memoization, recursive Fibonacci becomes infeasible before you hit the 50th Fibonacci number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is the following

```
def fibo_up_to(n):
    if n < 2:
        return [1,1]
    else:
        L = fibo_up_to(n-1)
        if L[-1] < n:
            L.append(L[-1] + L[-2])
        return L
```

the idea is that to return the list of all fibonacci numbers less than `n` you can ask for the list of those less than `n-1` and then possibly add just one element. This works from 2 on if we define the first two numbers being `[1, 1]`. Using `[0, 1]` instead creates a problem for 2 because a single next element is not enough.

This code is not inefficient on time (fibonacci is a double recursion, this is a simple recursion), but uses a lot of stack space.

Answer (score 1):

```
 def calculate_fibonnaci(n):
     if n == 0:
         return 0
     if n == 1:
         return 1
     else:
         return calculate_fibonnaci(n - 1) + calculate_fibonnaci(n - 2)
```

Here's a simple solution using a recursive function.